# Urban Airship set custom download directory

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

Is there anyone who know how to set a custom directory in UA's StoreFront?

With Apple's new rules about where data is stored there is a problem with UA's normal way to do it in /Library/ua/download.

It needs to be set to /Library/Cashes/ua/download.
They have a place in the StoreFront;

```
+ (BOOL)setDownloadDirectory:(NSString *)path;
+ (BOOL)setDownloadDirectory:(NSString *)path withProductIDSubdir:(BOOL)makeSubdir;
```

But I don't know how to change the 'path'.
Anyone out there that have fixed it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Look here :
https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/questions/66315-rejected-app-with-2-23-ios-data-storage-guidelines

for how to changeThePat.

After that you will ned to change the paths in the `UAGlobal.h`.

Look for a file named: `UAGlobal.h` inside Urban Airship files

You will find there paths, like

```
   #define kPendingProductsFile [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,\
    NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString: @"/ua/pendingProducts.history"];
```

I believe you can simply change the paths ends.

Good luck

Shani